# Align a RelativeLayout inside a RecyclerView to the right

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop a Whatsapp like Activity when you chat with someone. I have been able to create something like below:

[image]

Chat messages here are of 2 types - Sent and Received. I want the Received messages to be on the left side and Sent messages to be on right side. For this, I have created a RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager the following layouts for the left and right side alignments:

**Layout for the received messages i.e to be displayed on the left.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_view_border">

    <!--The message text-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <!--the timestamp-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout for the sent messages i.e to be displayed on the right.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_view_border"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">

    <!--The message text-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <!--the timestamp-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem:** As you can see in the image, the message to be displayed on the right(with the text "rtdfg") is not being done so. I don't understand, why it won't do so even after setting the layout_gravity to right on the RelativeLayout.

Can anyone throw light on why this is happening and how do I align it to the right?

**EDIT 1:** I am providing the Activity where I am doing the work for your reference.

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ChatMessagesAdapter chatMessagesAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        //Get the root view that is the recycler view
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.chart_activity_recycler_view);

        //Set up the layout manager for the RecyclerView
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        //Attach the adapter to the RecyclerView
        chatMessagesAdapter = new ChatMessagesAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(chatMessagesAdapter);

        //Retrieve the added text
        final EditText typedText = (EditText)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.typed_message);
        //Setup the listener on the send button.
        Button sendButton = (Button)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //On clicking the send button, update the adapter source and as the adapter source gets updated,
                //trigger notification of the adapter with the updated data source.
                //Secondly, ensure that the type of message that gets displayed varies for Sender versus Receiver
                //as in Left vs Right

                //If the "typed" message is empty then no point in sending it.
                String typedMessageText = typedText.getText().toString();
                if(typedMessageText.isEmpty()){
                    return;
                }
                //Construct the message typed by the Sender
                Message messageFromSender = new Message();

                //Set the message text from the typed message EditText
                messageFromSender.setMessageText(typedText.getText().toString());
                messageFromSender.setUserStatus(Message.SENDER);
                //For the timestamp, retrieve the time-stamp from the system
                messageFromSender.setTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L);
                chatMessagesAdapter.getChatMessagesSource().add(messageFromSender);

                //Now, notify the adapter of the change in source
                chatMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ChatMessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

        //Initialize the source from the JSON file having messages
        private List<Message> messageList = getListOfSenderMessagesFromJSONSource();

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position){
            int viewType = messageList.get(position).getUserStatus();
            if(viewType == Message.RECEIVER){
                return Message.RECEIVER;
            }
            else if(viewType == Message.SENDER){
                return Message.SENDER;
            }
            else if(viewType == Message.DATE_DIVIDER){
                return Message.DATE_DIVIDER;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){
            //Add the code for constructing a ViewHolder
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ChatActivity.this);
            RelativeLayout viewGroup1;
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            switch(viewType){
                case Message.RECEIVER:
                    viewGroup1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_receiver, viewGroup, false);
                    viewHolder = new ChatMessageViewHolder(viewGroup1);
                    break;
                case Message.SENDER:
                    viewGroup1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_sender, viewGroup, false);
                    viewHolder = new ChatMessageViewHolder(viewGroup1);
                    break;
                default:   //I know its not a good idea to return a receiver message template as default but for now it suffices
                    viewGroup1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_message_receiver, viewGroup, false);
                    viewHolder = new ChatMessageViewHolder(viewGroup1);
                    break;
            }
            return viewHolder;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
            switch(viewHolder.getItemViewType()){
                case Message.RECEIVER:
                    ((ChatMessageViewHolder)viewHolder).bindMessage(messageList.get(position));
                    break;
                case Message.SENDER:
                    ((ChatMessageViewHolder)viewHolder).bindMessage(messageList.get(position));
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){
            return messageList.size();
        }

        private List<Message> getListOfSenderMessagesFromJSONSource(){
            List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();

            //Parse the given JSONFile to get the individual messages
            //Name of the file: sampleChats.json

            Message chatMessage = null;
            try {
                JSONArray rootJSONArray =  new JSONArray(Message.chatMessagesJSONString);
                JSONArray level1JSONArray = (JSONArray)rootJSONArray.get(0);
                JSONObject jsonObjectInsideLevel1Array = level1JSONArray.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject messageObject = jsonObjectInsideLevel1Array.getJSONObject("message").getJSONObject("pn_gcm").getJSONObject("data");
            /*Retrieved message object has the following structure
            "data": {
          "name": "Dr. Renu Gupta",
          "userType": "doctor",
          "timestamp": 1480535381,
          "senderId": "1578",
          "text": "Hi Fgdfgdgf!",
          "type": "chat",
          "cardType": "text",
          "notificationType": "QChat"
            }
            * */
                //Populate the fields with the fields from JSON data
                String senderName = messageObject.getString("name");
                String userType = messageObject.getString("userType");
                long timeStamp = messageObject.getInt("timestamp");
                long senderId = messageObject.getInt("senderId");
                String messageText = messageObject.getString("text");
                String messageType = messageObject.getString("type");
                String cardType = messageObject.getString("cardType");
                String notificationType = messageObject.getString("notificationType");

                //Populate the message list with the retrieved JSON object
                chatMessage = new Message();
                chatMessage.setSenderName(senderName);
                chatMessage.setUserType(userType);
                chatMessage.setSenderID(senderId);
                chatMessage.setTimeStamp(timeStamp);
                chatMessage.setMessageText(messageText);
                chatMessage.setMessageType(messageType);
                chatMessage.setCardType(cardType);
                chatMessage.setNotificationType(notificationType);

                //Don't forget to set the sender status
                chatMessage.setUserStatus(Message.RECEIVER);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            messageList.add(chatMessage);
            return messageList;
        }

        public List<Message> getChatMessagesSource(){
            return messageList;
        }

    }

    private class ChatMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        //Root view
        private View messageView;
        //Child views
        private TextView chatMessageContent;
        private TextView timeStamp;

        private Message toBeBindedChatMessage;

        Drawable placeHolder;

        public ChatMessageViewHolder(View displayMessageView){
            super(displayMessageView);
            messageView = displayMessageView;
            chatMessageContent = (TextView)messageView.findViewById(R.id.message_content);
            timeStamp = (TextView)messageView.findViewById(R.id.time_stamp);
            placeHolder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dante_dmc_623_350);
        }
        public void bindMessage(Message toBeBindedChatMessage){
            this.toBeBindedChatMessage = toBeBindedChatMessage;

            //Bind the view with messsage object
            //Bind the message content
            chatMessageContent.setText(toBeBindedChatMessage.getMessageText());
            //Bind the Time Stamp
            timeStamp.setText(Message.timeStampToHH_MMFormat(toBeBindedChatMessage.getTimeStamp()*1000));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're kind of going down the wrong path by using a linear layout there.  Think about an active conversation-  you'll have dozens of them.  You want a ListView, not a LinearLayout.

Comment: Try using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of `"wrap_content"`. You need to `RelativeLayout` to be on the right side. Alternatively, try setting `android:layout_gravity="right"` (or `"end"`) for the right-side rows. (@GabeSechan - OP is using a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` That's just as good as a `ListView` for OP's purposes.)

Comment: @GabeSechan : No, I am using it in a RecyclerView so the Adapter takes care of addition and deletion of new messages. It is the LinearLayoutManager that has been passed to the RecyclerView

Comment: @pulp_fiction Ah, ok.  You don't show that in what you posted :)

Comment: But you should be able to get that effect by setting the layout_gravity of your relative layout to left or right.

Comment: @GabeSechan : Exactly. But its not so I thought maybe its something about RecyclerView that's complicating it but unable to figure out.

Answer (score 6):

For a quick fix do this.

`RelativeLayout`'s width should `match_parent` for it to occupy the entire width of it's container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_view_border"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <!--The message text-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <!--the timestamp-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem in my previous project with RecyclerView and unable to find the solution.

I have also tried with ListView and BaseAdapter. For that I was using viewholder and faced exactly same alignment issue. I was not able to figure out what is the issue with viewHolder!  **I fixed the issue by removing viewHolder**.

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messageList = messageList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = messageList.get(position).getUserStatus();
        Message message=messageList.get(position);
            if(viewType == Message.RECEIVER){
                 convertView = receiverLayout(convertView,message);
            }
            else if(viewType == Message.SENDER){
                convertView = senderLayout(convertView,message);
            }
        return convertView;
    }

    private View receiverLayout(View convertView, final Message messages) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_chat_receive, null);
        // Do your stuff for receiver
        return convertView;
    }

    private View senderLayout(View convertView, final Message messages) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_chat_send, null);
         // Do your stuff for sender
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your main container a `RelativeLayout` and set it's width to `"match_parent"`.
 After, put the two TextViews for *message_content* and *time_stamp*  in a `LinearLayout`. 
Set the width and height of that LinearLayout to `wrap_content`.
 Then now, you can `alignToParentRight` or `alignToParentLeft`. **Like this below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dp">
       <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_view_border"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignToParentRight="true">

<!--The message text-->
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/message_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold"/>
<!--the timestamp-->
        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
         android:textStyle="bold"/>
     </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution to keep your relative layout to right aligned.

```css
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That might work but I was wondering if it was possible to do it directly with RelativeLayout...

Comment: to achieve your requirement  you can set layout_gravity left and right alternatively  in your adapter. so using above same layout you will achieve both left and right alignment.

Comment: You can use alighParentRight inside the textview, if you want to do it directly with RelativeLayout

Comment: I tried this solution too and used LinearLayout as a wrapper. It is not working either. I think there is something deep about RecyclerView itself. I mean, in the Layout design view, it shows the layout on the right which is the normally expected outcome. I have no idea in the slightest what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

If `LinearLayout` is the parent,then we can't set the

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to it's child's.

Instead set

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to parent(LinearLayout) itself.Then it will arrange all childs from right to left

But in your case,using a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout is better.

Comment: But if I supply android:layout_gravity = "right" to the RelativeLayout then it is intended for the parent to arrange its views. Parent in this case is a LinearLayout. And of you see the code, I have supplied it. It still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the code of the wrapper which the RelativeLayout's or in. It looks like the wrapper width is not enough. If you want it to bo on the screen's most right make the wrapper "match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

After banging head with countless blogs and Android source, I couldn't find any elegant solution to this problem but a non-elegant one I have found is after much hit and trial is provided:

**Modified Layout for sender: Option 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_view_border"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right">

        <!--The message text-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!--the timestamp-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Modified Layout for sender: Option 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_view_border"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right">

        <!--The message text-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!--the timestamp-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/message_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see there is no reason it should or shouldn't work. I mean, the correct outcome is the result of an undefined behavior. One key aspect of the above code is that it doesn't align to the right if I don't provide `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in the nested the RelativeLayout. I was wondering if anyone can help me figure that out.

I am posting some points I gathered about Layouts from Android source so that others can benefit from it:

- `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` class handles just layout_width and layout_height.
- `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` class handles margins and width/height
- Any other viewgroup specific layout parameter details(in addition to width, height and margins) are handled by respective classes like `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, etc.
- All the common LayoutParams handle layout_gravity/gravity EXCEPT `RecyclerView.LayoutParams`. It doesn't handle align_parent either(I confirmed this from the Gravity handling code inside the respective classes)

Answer (score 0):

Have the parent RelativeLayout of the textviews be backgroundless, have the textviews alignParentEnd="true" and put the background on them, they will appear on the right/left regardless if their parent is taking up all the width or not :) just a visual trick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `RelativeLayout` you can also use `ConstraintLayout` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. Inside it you should align messages to the right using `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`. It will be helpful for complex layouts with text, images, date, where `RelativeLayout` is not so simple.

If it is not so easy or not successful, try to wrap your layout into:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <!-- Your message layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

        ...

    </LinearLayout

</FrameLayout>
```